# jquery Get innerWidth() using id

Tags: jquery

How can i get the width of an element by using it's id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#yourId').innerWidth() //is for innerWidth
$('#yourId').width() //returns the width
```

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/FHC87/